# LDAP DirectorySearcher.sort missing records with not set values

Tags: model-view-controller, active-directory, ldap

When querying against our AD, we get a full result set on the initial query `(samaccounttype=805306368)`.  If we then try to sort the query on a field where the value can be `<not set>` such as `givenname`, it will only return the records with a value set and skips records without the value.  We have tried using the below presence flag to include both sets but still loose the not set values when sorting:

```
(|(&(samaccounttype=805306368)(givenName=*))(&(samaccounttype=805306368)(!givenname=*)))
```

Not sure if it is related to how the `VirtualListView` is handling the results set or if there is another problem.   Has anyone run in to this before and any suggestions on what I'm missing?  Here's the code snip for the `ds.virtuallistview` sorting.

```
using (var ds = new DirectorySearcher(de))
            {
                ds.Filter = Filter;

                foreach (var p in Properties)
                {
                    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add(p.LDAPName);
                }

                //get record count
                ds.PropertyNamesOnly = false;
                ds.Sort = new SortOption(this.Properties.PrimaryOrderBy.LDAPName, SortDirection.Ascending); //ldap must always return ascending so we can custom sort
                ds.VirtualListView = new DirectoryVirtualListView(0, 0, 0);
                foreach(SearchResult s in ds.FindAll()){ /*must enumerate the collection before calling approximate total*/ }
                Records = ds.VirtualListView.ApproximateTotal;
                results = ds.FindAll();
                //Records = results.Count;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example code of DirectorySearcher which sort the result on `givenName`.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
   /* Connection to Active Directory
    */
   DirectoryEntry deBase = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://WM2008R2ENT:389/dc=dom,dc=fr");

   /* Directory Search
    */
   DirectorySearcher dsLookFor = new DirectorySearcher(deBase);
   dsLookFor.Filter = "(sn=users)";
   dsLookFor.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
   dsLookFor.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
   dsLookFor.PropertiesToLoad.Add("givenName");
   dsLookFor.PropertiesToLoad.Add("telephoneNumber");

   dsLookFor.Sort = new SortOption("givenName", SortDirection.Descending);

   SearchResultCollection srcUsers = dsLookFor.FindAll();

   foreach (SearchResult sruser in srcUsers)
   {
     Console.WriteLine("{0}", sruser.Path);

     foreach (string property in sruser.Properties.PropertyNames)
     {
       Console.WriteLine("\t{0} : {1} ", property, sruser.Properties[property][0]);          
     }
   }
 }
```

You can see in the following result that the `givenName` is no set for `user1 users` but the object appears in the result at the end of the list. I do not use the `VirtualListView`.

```
LDAP://WM2008R2ENT:389/CN=user0 users,OU=MonOu,DC=dom,DC=fr
        givenname : user0
        telephonenumber : 88
        adspath : LDAP://WM2008R2ENT:389/CN=user0 users,OU=MonOu,DC=dom,DC=fr
        cn : user0 users
LDAP://WM2008R2ENT:389/CN=user2 users,OU=MonOu,DC=dom,DC=fr
        givenname : user2
        adspath : LDAP://WM2008R2ENT:389/CN=user2 users,OU=MonOu,DC=dom,DC=fr
        cn : user2 users
LDAP://WM2008R2ENT:389/CN=user1 users,OU=MonOu,DC=dom,DC=fr
        telephonenumber : 99
        adspath : LDAP://WM2008R2ENT:389/CN=user1 users,OU=MonOu,DC=dom,DC=fr
        cn : user1 users
```

If I add the following line :

dsLookFor.VirtualListView = new DirectoryVirtualListView(1, 0, 2);

The result is :

```
LDAP://WM2008R2ENT:389/CN=user0 users,OU=MonOu,DC=dom,DC=fr
        givenname : user0
        telephonenumber : 88
        adspath : LDAP://WM2008R2ENT:389/CN=user0 users,OU=MonOu,DC=dom,DC=fr
        cn : user0 users
LDAP://WM2008R2ENT:389/CN=user2 users,OU=MonOu,DC=dom,DC=fr
        givenname : user2
        telephonenumber : 55
        adspath : LDAP://WM2008R2ENT:389/CN=user2 users,OU=MonOu,DC=dom,DC=fr
        cn : user2 users
```

The results whithout given Name is missing.